# Card Elevation Jumping

Tags: android

I have a Viewpager with CardViews.
When I scrolling the CardViews then the elevation is jumped.

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingBottom="16dp">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/card"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        card_view:cardPreventCornerOverlap="true"
        card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
        android:translationZ="10dp"
        card_view:cardElevation="6dp"
        card_view:contentPadding="24dp">
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
</FrameLayout>



        cardViewPager.apply {
            adapter = CardPagerAdapter(layoutInflater, list)
            clipToPadding = false
        }
```

Someone have idea why is it happening?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was:

My Cardview were in a `FrameLayout`. Don't do it! Just a `<CardView..`  in your layout!

Answer (score 0):

It is not jumping. Its just last swiped view shadow is hiding.And that is taking little more time than expected so it looks like that. Reduce your card view elevation may solve your problem.

```
card_view:cardElevation="2dp"
```

Comment: But I want to add a big elevation to the bottom side. :/ No way?

Comment: most probably no. But try to add padding or margin to restrict the range of elevation around the card view. it may work for you.

Comment: It's "jumping" too. But harder to notice it